# Deployment via gitlab-ci for multiple environments

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a react project for which I want to set up deployment via gitlab for both development and production environments. Following is my script in `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the development branch:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building ..."
    - "#!/bin/sh"
    - chmod og= $SERVER_PASSWORD
    - echo "Updating repository ..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "cd /home/dev/my-react-project && git pull"
    - echo "Installing changes from package.json ..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && cd /home/dev/my-react-project && npm install"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ..."
    - "#!/bin/sh"
    - chmod og= $SERVER_PASSWORD
    - echo "Restarting pm2..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && cd /home/dev/my-react-project && npm run dev-pm2"
    - echo "Deployment completed"
  environment:
    name: development
    url: http://123.456.78.90:4110
  only:
    - develop
  when: manual
```

This works perfectly fine and I can deploy my app from gitlab itself.

Now, I have something similar in the master branch for the production environment:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building ..."
    - "#!/bin/sh"
    - chmod og= $SERVER_PASSWORD
    - echo "Updating repository ..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "cd /home/prod/my-react-project && git pull"
    - echo "Installing changes from package.json ..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && cd /home/prod/my-react-project && npm install"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ..."
    - "#!/bin/sh"
    - chmod og= $SERVER_PASSWORD
    - echo "Restarting pm2..."
    - ssh -i "$SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_ADDRESS "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && cd /home/prod/my-react-project && npm run prod-pm2"
    - echo "Deployment completed"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://123.456.78.90:4000
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

Except a few changes like the folder path and the port number, everything else is the same. But in this case, I get the following error:

```
$ echo "Building ..."
Building ...
$ #!/bin/sh
$ chmod og= $SERVER_PASSWORD
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.
Usage: chmod [-Rcvf] MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
Each MODE is one or more of the letters ugoa, one of the
symbols +-= and one or more of the letters rwxst
    -R  Recurse
    -c  List changed files
    -v  List all files
    -f  Hide errors
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong here and what could be the issue? Even if I copy the entire script of `.gitlab-ci.yml` from the development branch into master branch, I still get the same error although it is working perfectly fine in development branch. And this is just the front-end. I need to deploy the backend written in NodeJS as well. So there are a total of 4 scripts out of which only one works. Is it something like only one deployment script per server/ip? I have not been able to find an answer to this. Could anyone help?

Comment: Hope you have resolved this issue. In case not, then I would think that your $SERVER_PASSWORD variable which you may have stored as a GitLab env variable is protected and is not getting sourced in your "build" stage. also its a chmod error so the $SERVER_PASSWORD is coming out as empty.